# Equivalent Rational functions over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, rational-functions

I want to prove a result and I think I have done it, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not. I am working on permutation polynomials over finite fields, where I want to prove a rational function  $$f(x)= \frac{-x^7-x^6+x^4+x+1}{x^7+x^6+x^3-x-1}$$ as one over $\mu_{2^{m+1}}$ where $\mu_d$ is defined as $$\mu_d= \{x \in  \bar{\mathbb F_{q}}: x^d=1 \}$$, $ \mathbb F_{q}$ is finite field with $q$ elements and $\bar{\mathbb F_{q}}$ is algebraic closure of  $ \mathbb F_{q}$.

As we know to prove a function one, we usually equate $f(x)=f(y)$ and conclude that $x=y.$
Using the similar methodology, I equated $f(x)=f(y)$ i.e. $$\frac{-x^7-x^6+x^4+x+1}{x^7+x^6+x^3-x-1}= \frac{-y^7-y^6+y^4+y+1}{y^7+y^6+y^3-y-1}$$.

Both left-hand side and right-hand side are rational functions. Therefore, they must be equal in their lowest form. Thus,

\begin{equation}
-x^7-x^6+x^4+x+1 =-y^7-y^6+y^4+y+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x^7+x^6+x^3-x-1 = y^7+y^6+y^3-y-1
\end{equation}
I am not sure about this step; can I equate these numerators and denominators over $\mu_{2^{m+1}}$ to do my further calculations?

Comment: It is hard to parse what you want, but it is definitely not true that $f=1$ --- just choose $m$ large enough so there are enough equations to determine the 13 coefficients of a [7/7], or note that the denominator must have a zero in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$.

Comment: You cannot separate the numerators and denominators like that without an extra argument. The assumption that the order of $x$ (and $y$) is a power of two must play a role. Here obviously $q=p^n$ with $p$ an odd prime (otherwise $\mu_{2^m}$ is trivial). Another immediate observation is the identity $f(1/x)=1/f(x)$ because polynomial in the numerator is the reciprocal of the denominator. Does not look useful, but you never know :-). That may come from the problem you originally wanted to solve.

Comment: For what range of values of $q$ have you verfied this numerically?

Comment: Anyway, as @user10354138 predicted, the claim does not hold universally. With $q=17$ I (or Mathematica) found $f(2)=f(4)$. I decided to test with $q=17$, because it is large enough for their argument to kick in, and also then all the non-zero elements of the field are in $\mu_{16}$.

Comment: So what is the problem that you really wanted to solve?